# How to define the calling program when using Iseries ODBC?

Tags: odbc, db2, ibm-midrange, rpg

Is there a way to define the calling 'program name' when using the Iseries ODBC driver? When I run a command against our AS400 using the Iseries Access ODBC driver, the calling program in the call stack of the as400 shows the program name as blank. I'd like to define one because we have a trigger that needs to know who is the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ODBC connection is proxied through a `QZDASOINIT` job.  I don't believe there is a way to identify the specific connection (or program) that fired the trigger.

Comment: To add to James' answer, any time there's a server/client interface, it's deliberate that each side operates without knowledge of the other.  Imagine a Java program running on Windows.  It might be com.mycompany.orderEntry.inventory.GetQuantity; it uses ODBC/JDBC to reach into DB2 for i.  How will the IBM i call stack know the exact name of the Java program that initiated the update?  The ODBC driver doesn't pass the name of the initiator to the server.

Comment: An additional thought. Depending on how your have setup your connection, if you use a different generic user for each application, you can see what the signed in user is by using option 2 on `WRKACTJOB`.

Answer (score 2):

As JamesA points out, all ODBC requests go through the `QZDASOINIT` job, so you can't change the call stack to determine the caller.

To get around this problem, DB2 for i includes client special registers that are automatically set by the ODBC driver (which you can override if you wish) and your trigger can then use. For more information see: http://ibmsystemsmag.blogs.com/i_can/2009/10/i-can-use-client-special-registers.html

Answer (score 0):

It's been possible for some time, exposed only since i 6.1. For an example usage, run this statement in i Nav 'Run SQL Scripts...':

```
select CURRENT CLIENT_APPLNAME, CURRENT CLIENT_PROGRAMID, CURRENT CLIENT_WRKSTNNAME from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Support is available to application developers using a JDBC, OLE DB, CLI, or .NET data provider. They can also be set by calling a special stored procedure.

Using IBMDASQL for example, a connection string might include:

```
conn.Open "Provider=IBMDASQL; Data Source=MyAS400;" & _
"Client User ID=MYWINUSRID; Client WorkStation Name=MYWINPC; " & _
"Client Program ID=somepc.exe; Application Name=Sample for Audit"
```

The SQL Reference discusses new "special registers".